# Reorder columns in numpy array based on content (count of a specific value)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Need some ideas on this. I'm sure there is a cleve pythonic way to do this without resorting to a 'cell wise' rebuild of the array.

**Background:**
I'm trying to manipulate a large summary out of a system we are using to collate crowd worker judgements. I'm formatting the data so it's in a suitable format to push though OpenBugs and possibly later PyMC.

I have a large np array in the following format, there are up to 500 cols and many 1000s of rows. This is a reduced example:

```
a = np.array([['a','b','c','d','e'],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [1, 2, 'na', 'na','na'],
          [1, 2, 'na', 4, 5]])
```

**Desired Result:** I want to reorder (ideally inplace) the columns of the data such that they are sorted by the number of `'na'` which appear in the column. NB i **don't** want to sort BY a col. Rather sort the columns themselves.

I'd like an option to specify how many leading columns are left alone (not moved) as this depends from time to time. And sort by ascending/descending. The top row is a header, who's values index the col. All values are either int or 'na', and the header is a string.

so in this example. If I want to leave `'a'` col in place, and sort by descending numbers of `'na` the output would be:

```
a = np.array([['a','c','d','e','b'],
              [1, 3, 4, 5, 2],
              [1, 'na', 'na', 'na',2],
              [1, 'na', 4, 5, 2]])
```

any clever array manipulation suggestions welcome!

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be -

```
N = 1 # No. of leading cols to be kept
out = a[:,np.r_[:N,(-(a[:,N:]=='na').sum(0)).argsort()+N]]
```

Basically, we are selecting all columns after `N`, comparing against `'na'` and getting the count per column with `.sum(0)` and getting argsort indices in descending order. Finally, we are concatenating with a range of indices uptil `N` with these `argsort` indices and indexing into the columns of input array to give us the desired output.

Sample runs -

```
In [89]: a
Out[89]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['1', '2', 'na', 'na', 'na'],
       ['1', '2', 'na', '4', '5']], 
      dtype='|S2')

In [90]: N = 1 # No. of leading cols to be kept

In [91]: a[:,np.r_[:N,(-(a[:,N:]=='na').sum(0)).argsort()+N]]
Out[91]: 
array([['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b'],
       ['1', '3', '4', '5', '2'],
       ['1', 'na', 'na', 'na', '2'],
       ['1', 'na', '4', '5', '2']], 
      dtype='|S2')

In [92]: N = 2 # No. of leading cols to be kept

In [93]: a[:,np.r_[:N,(-(a[:,N:]=='na').sum(0)).argsort()+N]]
Out[93]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['1', '2', 'na', 'na', 'na'],
       ['1', '2', 'na', '4', '5']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

If the order of columns that have equal counts of `'na'` doesn't matter, a more performant solution would be avoiding the `negation` of input array for getting that descending order by instead reversing the `argsort` indices without negation, like so -

```
a[:,np.r_[:N,(a[:,N:]=='na').sum(0).argsort()[::-1]+N]]
```